# Bootstrap 4 Pagination Scaling/Responsiveness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, bootstrap-4

I am using the pagination component in Bootstrap 4 as explained [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/pagination/).

I am able to successfully navigate through my pages as needed, however I noticed that the navigation buttons do not seem to be responding to screen size changes as I expected. For example, I am currently working with 16 pages, and when I view this on a mobile device or resize my browser to a smaller size I only see page buttons for page 4 through 14. I guess I was expecting the buttons to scale down as the page width was decreased, but this does not seem to be happening.

Details:

- I have added the meta tag for the viewport as needed by Bootstrap.
- I am using a container div to contain my pagination list.
- I am using the Bootstrap CDN, but it is loading properly.
- I did not include code example because I am following the Bootstrap example to a T.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 33):

Depending on the scenario one neat trick is the flex help class .flex-wrap together with .pagination to have your list break over multiple rows for smaller devices.

```
<ul class="pagination flex-wrap">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">A</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">B</a></li>
    ...
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Z</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is useful when you don't have too many pages and want them all visible without scrolling or such.

Answer (score 8):

Bootstrap's `Pagination` component doesn't have any sort of intelligent, responsive behaviors baked into it (like the Grid).  So when we're talking about the behavior you're describing... that's as expected.

The problem then becomes how do you address this shortcoming?  Scaling the buttons down as you suggest seems like a nice idea; but what if you have 100 pages?  If it has to scale to fit all 100 buttons on a single line those buttons are going to be exceedingly small.

So you have a couple of approaches that *are* baked into Bootstrap's `Pagination` component:

- Show X page numbers with `Prev` and `Next` buttons.
- The above, but with a `...` spacer to indicate there are additional pages

Or you can adjust the behavior of the `Pagination` component itself with a simple wrapper class: `.table-responsive`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav aria-label="Page navigation example" class="table-responsive mb-2">
  <ul class="pagination mb-0">
    <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">6</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">7</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">8</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">9</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">10</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">11</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">12</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">13</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">14</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">15</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">16</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">17</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">18</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">19</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">20</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

[ More Content Here ]
```

The `.table-responsive` class is designed to work with `<table>` and allow for horizontal scrolling when it would otherwise exceed 100% of the screen width... but it works perfectly fine here for providing a bit of utility if you want to incorporate all possible pagination options.

I hope you can appreciate though... this is ugly UX.  This is why so many pagination patterns follow the above bullet points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am going to upvote it. As far as it being ugly UX, I agree with you. When I realized that I might have any number of pages (potentially 50+) I decided to go a different route. I really just asked the question because I am trying to learn more details about Bootstrap and wanted to know what was going on in this case.

Comment: Pagination is one of those UI components that has just... a ton of good approaches depending on the scope of your project.  For something like yours - if you needed to show all page options... I'd probably just use a dropdown.

Comment: Please @robert can you kindly detail about the first option? I mean while in mobile switch the view to have fewer links and the "..." placeholder? Thank you. Maybe in bootstrap 5 flavor, just to update the reply. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested, on my web-application, I surround the `<ul>` with a navigation tag using a CSS class for a horizontal scrollbar.

```
<nav class="HORIZONTAL_SCROLL_NAV">
```

**Fiddle demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/JonathanParentLevesque/z4gL1wkb/5/

[image: Boostrap 4 pagination with a horizontal scrollbar]

The minimum CSS for this would be:

```
.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL_NAV {

    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden; 
}

.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL_NAV>ul {

    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can also add some additional CSS if you want to style the scrollbar (supported by those browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar):

```
.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL_NAV::-webkit-scrollbar {

    height: 10px;
}

.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL_NAV::-webkit-scrollbar-track {

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL_NAV::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some improvement for the answer by Dario Muñoz:

```
<ul class="pagination flex-wrap">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">A</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">B</a></li>
    ...
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Z</a></li>
</ul>
```

To make the pagination look nice you need to adjust the scss aswell:
The example is hardcoded but it should be possible to get the variables from the bootstrap's variables file.

```
.flex-wrap.pagination{
  margin-left: 3px;
  .page-item {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .page-item:first-child{
    margin-left: -3px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.pagination-sm .pagination-lg`

```
   <nav aria-label="...">
  <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
    <li class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```